# R: selecting top n rows using slice(arrange)

Tags: r, class, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to select the top 6 rows (by value) from a data frame in R using

```
top6 <- d %>%
filter(ReportingYear==2016) %>%
arrange(desc(total.emission)) %>%
slice(1:6)
```

but it returns all the rows in d. 
I couldn't understand this behaviour until I realised that there was something odd to me about the object d that is at the start of the pipeline.

```
> class(T4.d)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

The object d is created using

```
  d <- facilities %>%
  left_join(releases) %>%  #get activity id
  filter(PollutantName == "Methane (CH4)" & ActivityCode=="5.(d)") %>% 
  #filter for pollutant and activity
  group_by(CountryName,ReportingYear) %>% #group
  summarise(total.emission = sum(TotalQuantity)) #summarise
```

With

```
> class(facilities)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Given that facilities is a data frame, I was expecting the class of d to be data frame too. It seems to me that d is of a different class. Can somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Check the output after `filter`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: This question is pretty clear, and I can offer a helpful answer. Please reopen it so I can do that.